# Download Google Play Services

Tags: android, error-handling, google-play-services

In my android app I use google play services to view google maps

When a device does now have google play services installed, android shows a button says "Get Google Play Services" 
this button is from android itself, i did not create it.

the problem is that when ever user click on that button, app crashes.

I tried to trace the code and debug but there is no code for this ( i did not create any code for it)

I get this error, not sure how this can be resolved.

any ideas?

Thanks

```
05-06 23:58:17.730    2695-2695/com.asmgx.schlogger.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-06 23:58:17.730    2695-2695/com.asmgx.schlogger.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.asmgx.schlogger.app, PID: 2695
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1781)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: The device on which you are using code is running on which Android OS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive this error because you are running your code on an Android device that doesn't have the Google Play Store.

You can check if your intent will succeed like this:

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    //There isn't an app that handle your intent
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is fixing the error - The intent is not created by the developer, it is launched by the button created by google when the google service are not present on the device...